# Will spring-cloud-stream Kafka consumer not consume messages that were sent when the service was down?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a spring cloud stream Kafka consumer service where Acknowledgments are done manually . A fixed consumer group is provided.

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=sampleconsumergroup

The resetoffsets and startOffset properties are set as below
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.resetOffsets=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.startOffset=latest

The consumer service listens to a topic pattern.

Scenario: The consumer service is down and during this period some messages are send to it's topic. When the consumer service comes back up these messages are not consumed. Only the messages sent after it has come back online are consumed.

Is this as expected? I'm in the Kafka learning phase and an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are explicitly telling the binder to do that with

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.resetOffsets=true 
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.startOffset=latest
```

just remove those properties; bindings with groups will normally provide the behavior you desire.

Comment: I understand that startOffset=latest will make the consumer listen from the last committed offset. What happens internally when resetOffsets is true?

Comment: `startOffset` is used for new consumers (groups) only, unless `resetOffsets` is true, in which case, the binder does a `seekToBeginning()` or `seekToEnd()` for all assigned partitions during startup. If the [documentation for this property](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.1.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties) is not clear, please open a GitHub issue against the binder with suggestions for clarification.

Comment: _bindings with groups will normally provide the behavior you desire_. Just the opposite! According to the [latest documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties), _"if the consumer group is set explicitly ..., 'startOffset' is set to earliest"_ which causes all messages to be consumed starting from the oldest ones.

Answer (score 6):

Normally when a consumer joins a consumer group it will fetch from the last committed offset.

The startOffSet property have two options earliest and latest.These options are used when a consumer starts but there is no committed offset for the assigned partition.

In your scenario, your are not committing the offset after reading from the assigned partition due to which when your consumer service comes back , it is only reading the latest messages only.

Comment: Thanks. However " you're not committing the offset after reading from the assigned partition" . can you elaborate on this?          Manual acknowledgement is done after the message is successfully consumed and processed. I have not read from the topic at all since the consumer was down.

Comment: committing a offset is a marker in the assigned partition like i have read from offset 0 to 4 next time i have to read further. this can be done by setting ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG to true in the consumer property.